# ASP.NET Access POST data

Tags: asp.net, post, http-post

A 3rd party service is POSTing some data to our script. I can see this happening in our logs:

2014-10-21 06:20:34 185.x.x.7 POST /Notification.aspx q=xxxx 443 - 195.x.x.14 Java/1.7.0_67 301 0 0 0

How can I access that post data? I tried both

```
string s = "";
foreach (string name in Request.Form)
{
s += Request.Form[name] + "<br />";
}
```

and

```
string s = Request.Form.ToString();
```

Both of those are an empty string.

Thanks

Comment: try `Request.QueryString["q"];`

Comment: Are you sure the data you expect is posted? I see that there is a POST to the page, but there is also a Querystring there (q). Maybe your expected data is in QueryString?

Comment: The querystring is expected. We send that notification url to them and the querystring contains a value we use to identify what their post relates to. The post values should be seperate.